# jQuery Ajax: Variable as Header key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js

So currently im working with emberjs and i try to set the header of a request this way with variables:

```
 Ember.$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.requestEndpoint,
            headers: {`${headerName}`: headerValue}
        })
```

But the problem is that in `` headers: {`${headerName}`: headerValue} `` the ` is a unexpected token. 
Do you have an idea to solve that problem?

Edit: Just to make sure headerName and headerValue are the variables.

```
var name = headerName;
        var val = headerValue;
        var obj = {
           headerName:name,
           headerValue:val
        };
        Ember.$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.requestEndpoint,
            headers: {obj.headerName: obj.headerValue}
        })
```

gets the error:

```
Build error

client/controllers/workouts.js (in /opt/client/tmp/babel-input_base_path-LBKF5l2Q.tmp/0)

client/controllers/workouts.js: Unexpected token (19:22)
SyntaxError: client/controllers/workouts.js: Unexpected token (19:22)
  17 |          type: "GET",
  18 |          url: this.requestEndpoint,
> 19 |          headers: {obj.headerName: obj.headerValue}
     |                       ^
  20 |      }).success(function(data) {
  21 |          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  22 |          return data;
    at Parser.pp.raise (/opt/client/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/opt/client/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:82:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (/opt/client/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:76:33)
    at Parser.pp.parseObj (/opt/client/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:596:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/opt/client/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:392:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/opt/client/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:236:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/opt/client/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:217:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/opt/client/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:163:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/opt/client/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:145:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/opt/client/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:112:19)
```

Comment: As i can see you are trying to do the string interpolation with `headerName` and just want to know are you using some js compiler like babel?

Comment: seriously: i dont know. I have emberjs , vedor , handlebars. A string interpolation is not a must have. If there would be another way i would be happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `

```
`${headerName}`
```

back ticks are used for string interpolation in ES6 standard, so for this you have to use a js compiler like babel, which compiles the ES6 code down to the ES5 which runs in the browser in todays date, soon ES6 will be available in the browsers to use but as of now we have to compile down to run it.

And as per your comment i can suggest that you can store it in an object:

```
    var name = headerName;
    var val = headerValue;
    var obj = {};

    obj[name] = val; // outputs {Auth:Authstring}
```

and then you can refer it in your ajax:

```
 Ember.$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: this.requestEndpoint,
        headers: {obj.headerName: obj.headerValue} // <---use it here then
    })
```

```js
var headerName = "Ember";
var headerValue = "JS Framework";
var obj = {
  headerName: headerName, // you have to store the string value in a var as above.
  headerValue: headerValue
};

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the ES6 explination. I though ES6 would be standart. Unfortunately its not working. It return `Unexpected token (17:22)` for the obj.headerName. He do not expect the dot. I think because it has to be a string somehow..

Comment: the `.headerName` in the `obj` should be a string and if you have stored it in a var named `headerName` then that would be available to access it. Let me show you a simple demo.

Comment: @orgertot check the added snippet. What  i meant to say you have to set the `headerName, headerValue` values to some vars some where.

Comment: i did the same thing.. but it is not working :( i added the code and error to my question. Thanks for your time by the way :)

Comment: @orgertot actually your original code should work as Ember is using babel compiler, i guess your code is not able to set the values for `${headerName}` and `${headerValue}`.

Comment: but if i use console.log infront of the ajax headerName and headerValue are correct... :/

Comment: okay then you can use this and see what happens: `headers:obj`. as headers is also refering to an object so we can refer to our `obj`.

Comment: Its now sending in the request: `headerName:Authorization` and `headerValue:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MiwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0QHRlc3QuZGUiLCJpYXQiOjE0NDg1MjgxNDUsImV4cCI6MTQ0OTEzMjk0NX0.epJNQSOk_dLlecz8mEjs5kLl6qnz8P_Q-AupT_74A_Y` so this both but together :D

Comment: Great. glad this helped ;D

Comment: But it didnt :D Because the key must be Authorization and the value the token :( Chat?

Comment: oh right! then you can change the object this way: `var obj = {}; obj[name] = val;`

Comment: orgertot. now finally glad to help you.